# HTML, order list with jquery, do it faster

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, traversal

This is my jquery code to order a list:

```
$('ul').on('change','input',function(e){
    var $ul,$checked,$unchecked;
    $ul = $(e.delegateTarget);
    // markup <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label></li>
    $checked = $ul.find('input:checked').closest('li');
    $unchecked = $ul.find('input:not(:checked)').closest('li');
    $ul.empty().append($checked).append($unchecked);
});
```

With more than 20 list elements, it takes some time to reorder. Do you have any suggestion to do this faster?

edit: here is my markup

```
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox"/>1</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox"/>2</label></li>
...
<li><label><input type="checkbox"/>98</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox"/>99</label></li>
```

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: it would be helpful to post some html. are you trying to make the checked checkbox the first one in the list?

Comment: hi DG3, I added my markup.
Yes, the checked chechboxes are first, followed by the unchecked elements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using string selectors you could pass `.filter()` a function, which should be quite a bit faster:

```
        $checked = $ul.find('input').filter(function () {
            return (this.checked);
        }).closest('li');
        $unchecked = $ul.find('input').filter(function () {
            return (!this.checked);
        }).closest('li');
```

I'm not sure what kind of boost this gives but it's something to try.